# Javascript : Filter list with element contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have below object -

```
[
{
 employeeId:1
 employeeName:"ABC"
},
{
 employeeId:2
 employeeName:"ABD"
},
{
 employeeId:3
 employeeName:"FEW"
},
{
 employeeId:4
 employeeName:"JKABL"
},]
```

I want to filter this list as per word provided on employeeName.

Eg. If employee name word provided :- AB ; then it should filter out -

```
[
    {
     employeeId:1
     employeeName:"ABC"
    },
    {
     employeeId:2
     employeeName:"ABD"
    },
    {
     employeeId:4
     employeeName:"JKABL"
    },]
```

As EmployeeIds 1,2 and 4 contains employeename with AB.

For this I tried -

```
object.filter(x=>x.employeeName.indexOf("AB")>-1)
```

This is returning empty array every time.

Second way I tried -

```
   var filteredObject=object.map(x=>{
 if(x.employeeName.indexOf("AB")>-1)
  return x;
});
```

This is returning undefined every time.

Comment: Why not regex? Seems like a good use-case.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with  the filter function. Your bug must be coming from elsewhere.  https://jsfiddle.net/4gmjnqfp/1/

Comment: You forgot the commas in your object. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to filter _and_ use Regex btw? And if it's a user filter regex is a bit clunky if the search input can vary, which I presume it will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a custom function which filter using `includes`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    employeeId: 1,
    employeeName: 'ABC',
  },
  {
    employeeId: 2,
    employeeName: 'ABD',
  },
  {
    employeeId: 3,
    employeeName: 'FEW',
  },
  {
    employeeId: 4,
    employeeName: 'JKABL',
  },
];

const filterName = (search) => {
  return data.filter((value) => value.employeeName.includes(search));
};

console.log(filterName('AB'));
```

Comment: I was thinking this too, but why isn't `.indexOf() > -1` working? I mean it's less clear, sure, but I'm a bit stumped why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for that. It wasn't MY data though :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this apporach.

```
let arr = [
{
 employeeId:1,
 employeeName:"ABC"
},
{
 employeeId:2,
 employeeName:"ABD"
},
{
 employeeId:3,
 employeeName:"FEW"
},
{
 employeeId:4,
 employeeName:"JKABL"
},];

let res = arr.filter((item) => item.employeeName.includes("AB"));
console.log(res);
```

OUTPUT :

```
[
  { employeeId: 1, employeeName: 'ABC' },
  { employeeId: 2, employeeName: 'ABD' },
  { employeeId: 4, employeeName: 'JKABL' }
]
```